# How can you find something inside cloud Firestore when you don't know the key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Now, consider that I have about a million users with userId (this would probably be a collection)

```
1234567
1223452
1223454
1223456
1223425
1225451
......
......
......
```

Now, each collection contains documents, which would look something like this

```
1234567 
  --- userauth 
  ------ email: any123@gmail.com
1223452
  --- userauth 
  ------ email: varun123@gmail.com
......
......
......
```

Now, If i want to find userId of a person having a particular email id (Say: any123@gmail.com), how would I do it?

For this question, I am operating inside of a Cloud Function.

Will it be more efficient than SQL?

**Update:** As answered I did something like this

```
class docStore() {
 constructor (firestore) {
  this.store = firestore 
 }

async query(collection, condition) {
        let colRef = this.store.collection(collection)
        if (_.isArray(condition)) {
            condition.forEach(predicate => {
                colRef = colRef.where(predicate.name, predicate.op, predicate.value)
            })
        }

        const results = []
        const snapshot = await colRef.get()
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            results.push({data: doc.data(), id:doc.id})
        })
        console.notice(results)
        return results
    }
```

}

Where `this.store` is `admin.firestore()`

And my query is this

```
const checkIfEmailExsist = await docStore.query(SIGNUP_TABLES.userAuth, ['email', '==', userEmail])
```

Here `docStore` is above class and I am referencing query inside it

This is giving me following error

> [2019-11-01T13:52:36.873Z] (node:94753)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Value for argument
>   "fieldPath" is not a valid field path. The path cannot be omitted.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you reviewed [how to make queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)?  Also, are you inside a cloud function or are you on the web?

Comment: I am using firebase functions and thanks, reviewing the link you shared.

Comment: @Kolban updated the question. I know the email address but not the userId

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answering that you were operating inside of Cloud functions, and thus using the admin API.  Here's the link again to [how to make a query to firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).

A simple function to demonstrate a query like the one above (I'm assuming a collection called 'users') is here:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

let db = admin.firestore();

exports.doQuery = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const queryRef = db.collection('users').where('email', '==', 'any123@gmail.com');

    queryRef.get().then((snap) => {
      if (snap.empty) {
        response.send('no result');
      } else {
        let result = '';
        snap.forEach((doc) => {
          result = result + doc.id + ' => ' + JSON.stringify(doc.data()) + '<br>';
        })
        response.send(result);
      }
    }).catch((err) => { response.send('error'); });

  });
```

In your example, though you show that there is an intermediate `userauth` level.  Assuming this is a map (and not, say, another collection or something), you can use a `FieldPath` to have your query traverse the map.  That query would look like this, and would still return the entire user document:

```js
    const queryRef = db.collection('userProfiles').where(
      new admin.firestore.FieldPath('userauth','email'), '==', 'any123@gmail.com');
```

As to the question of efficiency, this type of query (simple equality) will be pretty efficent to execute in firestore, as you get an index on every value by default.  More complex queries may be more expensive, and require you to [create an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).  Also, you are [only charged for the documents returned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) (with a minimum of one document for an empty result set).

Comparison with a SQL database would require actual performance testing, of course, and is a much broader question that would involve the full scope of the types of queries you are making, the full layout of the database, what indexes exist, are there other features (e.g. constraints) that you want out of the SQL database that aren't provided by firestore, are you optimizing cost, latency, or something else, etc.

Comment: Provided the `email` is first level child inside the documents of `users` collection. Means there is nothing like `userauth` object wrapping `email`.

Comment: Excellent catch, @SanketPatel.  I've extended the answer to show how to use a `FieldPath` to traverse a map like this.

Comment: @robsiemb Updated the question slightly, I was trying to map SQL queries to firestore but it appears so that wasn't bright idea. I will brew a fresh Api tonight to see if it works will mark it answered. In the meanwhile, Can you please check the question again?

Comment: @SanketPatel Slightly updated the question, would so love to hear your suggestions for the same

Comment: Hi @anny123, generally you [shouldn't extend a question in a new direction, but instead ask a new one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers).  That said, the new question is hard to answer without knowing how you plan to use the read data, and what type of object each level of the hierarchy is (collection, document, map).

Comment: @robsiemb Yeah, I know. As mentioned in the comment I haven't tried your solution and the question still remains the same. Since I would be brewing new APi, I thought it's best to have DB in the correct pattern. Anyway, I understood your point and would ask it as a new question. Thanks :)

Comment: @robsiemb Legit question update, I am getting following error ` Error: Value for argument "fieldPath" is not a valid field path. The path cannot be omitted.` Can you help me in figuring out what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: it is `'userauth'` . My DB is completely empty (just in case)

Comment: I'm not sure where the '.name', '.op' etc members are coming from in the foreach...  It seems like you might just want the [spread operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/) instead of a forEach in this case.  It seems likely that `predicate.name` is undefined (instead of a string or a FieldPath object), and so the where clause can't use it as a valid FieldPath.